# Running behavior of glucose, galactose and mannose in TLC

Tags: polarity, chromatography

I have separated the sugars glucose, galactose and mannose by thin-layer-chromatography. My question is why these sugar have different running behaviors and a separation is possible.
Glucose have the lowest Rf-value, then galactose and mannose have the highest Rf-value in my experiments.
I thought it might be something to do with the position of the $\ce{-OH}$ groups (axial, equatorial) but I have no firm explanation at the moment.

Thanks for every explanation concerning the topic.

Comment: Short answer: Every molecule that is not the enantiomer of a reference molecule will run *slightly* differently on a TLC. Glucose, mannose and galactose are all diastereomers so their physical properties differ so they will run differently.

Comment: Isn't the polarity the main reason for the different Rf-values? Is there a difference between these molecules or which other criteria has an impact on the Rf-value?

Comment: Well, yes. But different molecule structures (diastereomers) automatically mean different polarities. And there are other factors contributing as well, like the ability of the mobile phase to interact with the molecules in question. Compare *cis*- and *trans*-stilbene which can be separated by TLC (and silica chromatography).